# How to display the Chinese characters in the properties file generated by the Properties Editor plugin in the vscode

Tags: plugins, unicode

The properties file generated by the Properties Editor plugin display in vscode like this.

```
#\u8FDE\u63A5\u914D\u7F6E
#Redis\u670D\u52A1\u5668\u5730\u5740
redis.hostname = 10.0.0.1
#Redis\u670D\u52A1\u5668\u7AEF\u53E3
redis.port = 6379
#Redis\u670D\u52A1\u5668\u5BC6\u7801
```

I can not any plugin Properties Editor like eclipse in vscode. 
Just change some characters, not wanna open the large IDE like eclipse.

Comment: There are many web sites that will display Unicode values in character form. For example, https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter . Just copy and paste your values (e.g. `\u670D\u52A1\u5668\u5730\u5740`) into the **UTF-16** field on that web page, then click its **Convert** button to see the corresponding Chinese characters in the **Unicode text** field: `服务器地址`. Or am I misunderstanding your question, and you specifically want to do this within vscode?

Comment: I know the method that copy characters to a tool to translate them, but It's so complex. Is there any plugin deal them automatic?